# How to update table row with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to update a row of a table.

To add I used,

```
session.add(unit) #here unit is unit object of class unit
session.commit()
```

To update I tried,

```
session.merge(unit)
session.commit()
```

However, in the database there are other columns, e.g. `create_by`, `created_on`, `updated_on`, which are not set in the unit object, so these are set NULL upon the merge.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used merge(unit), by modifying model structure.
Initialization of create_by, created_on, updated_on etc. removed from constructor ***init**(...)*

Answer (score 4):

You can just modify properties of the class you use to represent the row and call `session.commit()`.  For example:

```
# Add a new user
user = User(name="John", age=20)
session.add(user)
session.commit()

# Modify the user we just added
user.age = 21
session.commit()
```